# How can I Convert M-file to RISC-V Assembly code?

Tags: riscv, matlab-coder, riscv32

I am new to RISC-V. I want to convert that MATLAB code(M-file) to RISC-V Assembly code, can anyone give some suggestions or inputs on how can I do it.

Regards, 
Yulia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: i know rather few things about m-files and stuff

Perhaps using https://github.com/csafonov/tinymc to generate c code and using gcc to compile into a risc-v binary might work.

Hope that helps nevertheless.

Regards
Joachim